# Проблема с написанием функции для преобразования времени

Tags: c++, время, типы-данных

У меня мало опыта в C++ и библиотека chrono показалась сложноватой для восприятия, поэтому решил немного упростить и убрать boiler-plate.
Класс EpochTime должен предоставлять время с начала эпохи, выраженное в разных временных промежутках. Уже есть приватный метод для получения наносекунд. Нужно написать метод для преобразования наносекунд в данную единицу измерения:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class EpochTime {
private:
    static std::chrono::nanoseconds since_epoch()
    {
        return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    }
    static long get(? duration_unit)//
    {   /**
        duration_unit: std::chrono::milliseconds,
                       std::chrono::microseconds,
                       std::chrono::nanoseconds
        и так далее...
        */
        return ?;
    }

public:
    static long hours()        { return EpochTime::get(std::chrono::hours);        }
    static long minutes()      { return EpochTime::get(std::chrono::minutes);      }
    static long seconds()      { return EpochTime::get(std::chrono::seconds);      }
    static long milliseconds() { return EpochTime::get(std::chrono::milliseconds); }
    static long microseconds() { return EpochTime::get(std::chrono::microseconds); }
    static long nanoseconds()  { return EpochTime::get(std::chrono::nanoseconds);  }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << EpochTime::hours();
    return 0;
}
```

`duration_unit` - собственно единица измерения из chrono. Возникает вопрос о типе этого аргумента и как правильно его передать в `duration_cast`.

Comment: `std::chrono::milliseconds` и т.п. - это разные типы, соответственно тут нужен шаблон. Однако на самом деле лучше разобраться с chrono, а не городить этот сомнительный велосипед.

Comment: Посмотрите на `struct timespec` из [man clock_gettime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) и все сразу упростится (особенно, если понимать, что `time_t` это то же, что и `int64_t` (целое со знаком, размером 8 байт))

Comment: Но это для линукса, не портируемое. Чтобы на windows перенести в chrono наверняка велосипеды реализованы

Comment: Я понял насколько в chrono все продумано. Система перевода единиц измерения действительно хороша в их исходном виде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Duration>
auto now() {
    auto _now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<Duration>(_now).time_since_epoch().count();
}

auto hours() {  return now<std::chrono::hours>(); }
auto nanoseconds() { return now<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(); }

int main() {
    std::cout << hours() << std::endl;
    std::cout << nanoseconds() << std::endl;
}
```